# Debian Jessie : dependency problems prevent configuration of libkrb5support0:amd64

Tags: debian, dpkg

I am running a docker container with the OS

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I am trying to install `openjdk-8-jdk`

It is definitely available in my apt source configured repos

```
# apt search openjdk-8-jdk
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
openjdk-8-jdk/unstable 8u275-b01-1 amd64
  OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)

openjdk-8-jdk-headless/unstable 8u275-b01-1 amd64
  OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
```

When I try to install it, I get the error

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkrb5support0:amd64:
 libkrb5support0:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.25); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkrb5support0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libk5crypto3:amd64:
 libk5crypto3:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.25); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libk5crypto3:amd64 depends on libkrb5support0 (>= 1.16); however:
  Package libkrb5support0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libk5crypto3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libkrb5support0:amd64
 libk5crypto3:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried the [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/485293) solution but it did not work and gave me the error

```
# dpkg --configure --pending
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 244 package 'libk5crypto3:amd64':
 Config-Version for package with inappropriate Status
```

What else can I check in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Debian Jessie (8) has been EOL since June 20th.

`openjdk-8-jdk` requires GLIBC 2.25 or greater but Jessie only has 2.19 which isn't sufficient. You could compile GLIBX 2.25 from source but that would cause many other things not function that depend on it and could make your system unusable.

The only viable option is to upgrade to Buster which has GLIBC 2.25.